# Need a web app (blog?) to record project details for self/team

Tags: project, alm

Im looking for some sort of system that will allow me to record a list of projects and then tag them with technologies/process etc used.  It should then be able to cross reference these, search, view a timeline, filter by person/client etc.

Initially I want this for my resume but I thought it would also be useful at work for my team.

Ideally, it will be a web app so it can be internally or externally visible and easily hosted.

I could create something to do this easily enough but time is money... Does anyone know of anything that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

I looked into an app called [hitask](http://www.hitask.com) for my team. it works pretty well at keeping track of tasks and who needs to do what. best of all its free and im pretty sure they host it. sounds like it'd do exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks but Im not looking for task management.  This is more for post-project so we can find people with skills to do future work and as resume for individuals.